# Как правильно сделать динамическую подброку всех возможных значений?

Tags: java, c++, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Есть задача со следующей информацией

**Входные данные:** На вход подается число n;

**Выходные данные** На основе входного n надо составить всевозможные значения парных символов `[]`

**Пример** дано число  1 на выходе `[]` , если 2 то `[][],[[]]` и тк .тд

Какой правильный ход алгоритма, как перебирать все варианты []?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кнут, *Искусство программирования*, том 4А, стр. 499, алгоритм P.

Вот он на С++ (одна из ваших меток).

```
void generate(int n)
{
    char* a = new char[2*n+2];
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
    {
        a[2*k-1] = '[';
        a[2*k]   = ']';
    }
    a[0] = ']';
    a[2*n+1] = 0;
    int m = 2*n - 1;

    for(;;)
    {
        cout << a+1 << endl;
        a[m] = ']';
        if (a[m-1] == ']')
        {
            a[m-- - 1] = '[';
            continue;
        }

        int j = m - 1;
        int k = 2*n - 1;
        while(a[j] == '[')
        {
            a[j--] = ']';
            a[k] = '[';
            k -= 2;
        }
        if (j == 0)
        {
            delete[] a;
            return;
        }
        a[j] = '[';
        m = 2*n-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я знаю одного юзера на сайте, который осилил книгу дракона. Теперь я знаю второго, кто осилил Кнута. Когда нибудь настанет момент, и я тоже что нибудь осилю, чтобы дотянуться до вас :)

Comment: мне лично рекурсивный вариант кажется понятнее) https://ideone.com/8Vnnp9

Comment: @pavel спасибо!!! Очень помог рекурсивный подход он элегантнее чем итеративный

Comment: А как этот алгоритм вообще называется?)